# How can I get web request statistics in JBoss 6 or 7?

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, jboss7.x

Does the JMX interface in JBoss AS 6.1 or 7, or a web admin console area, offer some basic values like total request count? Or is there logging of HTTP requests which only needs to be enabled so I can get standard web server log files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of JBoss 6 (and also 5) you can turn on logging information about incoming connections. You have to edit `server.xml` file in the `profile/deploy/jbossweb.sar` directory and uncomment these line:

```xml
<!-- Access logger -->

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
       prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".log"
       pattern="common" directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}" 
       resolveHosts="false" />
```

These allow you to turn on logging in Apache Web Server format.

Answer (score 0):

Write a filter or JMX bean to keep the count and other statistics for you.